# Azure Cloud Service - SSL Signing Certificate

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cloud-services

I have run into an issue with Azure cloud services that has me a bit stumped. I am working on a project that interacts with a 3rd party REST API which requires all requests to be signed with an SSL cert. In development or on a production VM this is a non-issue. The certificates are typically installed in the appropriate stores and then can be loaded by thumbprint, from a file on disk or from an embedded resource like this:

```
_certificate = new X509Certificate2(Properties.Resources.Cert,
                "password, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
```

I am now trying to migrate a portion of the system to Azure and am having difficulty getting the certificate working. The issue I believe is the intermediate certificate from Symantec that is not already installed. So far I have tried writing both Powershell and batch files (i.e. certutil), I have written C# code to walk the certificate chain as well as to iterate over the collection of certs and perform the various imports but none of them have allowed for a successful call with the cert.

Has anyone automated the installation and usage of a signing cert in an Azure cloud service and if so would you mind sharing the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was get the certificate file on the Azure Cloud service, and run a startup task ( in elevated mode ) to install the certificate into the machine store.

So, what you probably need to do is:

1. Write a .cmd or powershell script that installs the certificate. Be
   sure to bundle it with your app ( type = content, copy local = true
   )
2. Be sure to bundle the cert with your app OR write a powershell script / cmd script that downloads the certificate onto the azure
   cloud service
3. Write a startup task that calls the the installation script, that installs the certificate on the machine.

Information on startup tasks here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh180155.aspx. NOTE: You need to run in 'elevated' mode in order to install the certificate.

```
<Startup>
    <Task commandLine="Startup.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple" >
     </Task>
 </Startup>
```

Inside your `Startup.cmd` - for example:

```
certutil -addstore -enterprise -f -v root Certificates\mycert.cer
```

Taken from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/azure/en-US/96926ae6-0cbf-4d00-9dd4-bbe86f93737e/add-certificate-file-to-trusted-root-ca-using-startup-task). Again - make sure to bundle the cert in your host app, OR write a script that downloads the certificate from somehwere - before calling the `certutil` command.

Comment: Jochen,

Thank you for the assist. I had already tried this method and it was still failing so I debugged further and it turns out the 403 I was getting back was actually a 403.6 (blocked IP). The vendor stated they had already whitelisted the reserved IP but in fact they did not. Your snippet is the correct way to do this and I only need to install the intermediate cert this way which is great. Thank you.